# Clear TextBox's text on button click in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, storyboard

I'm working on a search box solution where there is no binded text as I'm using the `Text` property as parameter for the search command.
And that part works just fine.

Now I would like to clear the text in the `TextBox` using a "clear button" set at the end of the `TextBox`.

I tried with `EventTrigger`, but the `StoryBoard` block the `Command` and does not set the text to nil.

Below is my code.
Any idea?

```
<!--Search Box-->
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBox x:Name="FilterText">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding  Key="Enter" Command="{Binding FilterDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FilterText, Path=Text}"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5,0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTransparentStyle}" Command="{Binding ClearSearchCommand}">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FilterText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value=""/>
                        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
        <Image Source="/VisionRanger;component/Images/Icons/icon.clear.dark.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="4,3,2,4" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
<!--Search Button-->
<Button Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonTransparentStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Command="{Binding FilterDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FilterText, Path=Text}">
    <Image Source="/VisionRanger;component/Images/Icons/icon.search.dark.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: For clearing the text property use code behind in this case

Comment: What does the `ClearSearchCommand` do in this case? Is it redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way for me is to create a custom control. But I needed something that I could use quickly for a client's project so I created a style that leveraged the properties of a button to create a search "button" (Of course there were other styles involved) but they don't change the underlying principle used.

[image: Without Text]

And when there is text, clicking the close button will clear it.

[image: With Text]

```
<!--#region Search Button-->
<Style
    x:Key="SearchButton"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{StaticResource SearchIcon}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--#region Search Icon-->
                        <Border
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button
                                Name="icon"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                IsDefault="True"
                                Style="{StaticResource IconButton}" />
                        </Border>
                        <!--#endregion-->

                        <!--#region Text Box-->
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                            <TextBox
                                Name="text"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"                                  
                                ClipToBounds="True"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBoxWithPlaceHolder}"
                                Tag="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap">
                                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                    <KeyBinding
                                        Key="Enter"
                                        Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}" />
                                </TextBox.InputBindings>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Border>
                        <!--#endregion-->

                        <!--#region Close Icon-->
                        <Button
                            Name="close"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="5"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            IsCancel="True"
                            Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource IconSolid}" Text="{StaticResource CloseIcon}" />
                        </Button>
                        <!--#endregion-->

                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <!--#region Triggers-->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}" Value="">
                        <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        <Setter TargetName="close" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="close" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="" />                           
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!--#endregion-->

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!--#endregion-->
```

At any point in code, I define a button and call this style on it, and bind its command.

```
<Button
       Width="400"
       Height="50"
       Margin="10"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Background="Transparent"
       Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
       Style="{StaticResource SearchButton}" />
```

I believe there are better ways to do this but this has worked for me by far.

Answer (score 3):

The `Text` property is  **not animatable**, see [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) in the documentation. In the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,688), the [`FrameworkPropertyMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is initialized with  [`isAnimationProhibited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-frameworkpropertymetadata-ctor(system-object-system-windows-frameworkpropertymetadataoptions-system-windows-propertychangedcallback-system-windows-coercevaluecallback-system-boolean-system-windows-data-updatesourcetrigger)) set to `true`.

A solution would be to bind a `MyFilterTextProperty` property to the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in `TwoWay` mode (which is the default).

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyFilterTextProperty}"/>
```

Then in your command `ClearSearchCommand` you could clear `MyFilterTextProperty`.

```
public void ExecuteClearSearchCommand(/*...parameter.*/)
{
   MyFilterTextProperty = string.Empty;
   
   // ...other code.
}
```

---

An alternative is to clear the `TextBox` using a custom `TriggerAction`. Install the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/1.1.19) NuGet package. Create a custom trigger action like this. It exposes a dependency property `Target` that the `TextBox` can be bound to. If an event occurs, it clears it.

```
public class ClearTextTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Button>
{
   public static TextBox GetTarget(DependencyObject obj)
   {
      return (TextBox)obj.GetValue(TargetProperty);
   }

   public static void SetTarget(DependencyObject obj, int value)
   {
      obj.SetValue(TargetProperty, value);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Target", typeof(TextBox), typeof(ClearTextTriggerAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
   {
      GetTarget(this)?.Clear();
   }
}
```

In XAML you simply attach the behavior and bind `FilterText`

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5,0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTransparentStyle}" Command="{Binding ClearSearchCommand}">
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
       <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
          <local:ClearTextTriggerAction Target="{Binding ElementName=FilterText}"/>
       </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Image Source="/VisionRanger;component/Images/Icons/icon.clear.dark.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="4,3,2,4" Opacity="0.5"/>
</Button>
```

The `b` XML namespace for XAML bahviors must be included.

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Comment: @SirRufo Actually there is some strange behavior to it, as it works sometimes (like in this case), but you are right, it is not generally applicable, it should be avoided. Removed.